# Is this set open? What is the boundary?

Tags: general-topology

I have given this set

> $$ M = \{ x \in [1,2]\times [3,4] ~|~ x\in\mathbb{Q}^2 \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2 $$

First I have to identify the boundary $\partial M$ and then tell if it is open or closed.

I think that $$ \partial M = \{ (x,y) ~|~ x\not\in\mathbb{Q}^2, 1\leq x \leq 2, 3\leq y\leq 4 \} $$

is the boundary, but I am not sure about it. Is this correct? If not, what is the boundary?

Also: I am pretty sure that the set is open, because you can for sure find a series (e.g. for Pi) that converges to an irrational number, but with fraction series values in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz, $\Bbb Q^2$ is not closed. It's dense in fact.

Comment: To understand this problem more easily, do it in one dimension first. What is the boundary of the rationals in the unit interval?

Answer (score 1):

The set is not open or closed, because any open ball contains rational and irrational points.

To solve the problem, show that $\overline M=[1,2]\times[3,4]$ and $\overline{M^c}=\Bbb R^2$.

Then $\partial M=[1,2]\times[3,4]\cap \Bbb R^2$

Comment: Wait, so it is neither open nor closed? so what is it?

Comment: In a topological space, some sets are closed, some sets are open, some sets are none and some sets are both. Open and closed are not mutually exclusive or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Can you find an open ball containing $(1.5, 3.5)$ and totally contained in $M$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\overline M=[1,2]\times[3,4]$ and $\mathring M=\emptyset$, the boundary of $M$ is $\overline M\setminus\mathring M=[1,2]\times[3,4]$, which is a closed set.

Comment: Wait, but that means you say that every point in $[1,2]\times \{3\}$ is in the boundary. But not all elements of $[1,2]$ are in $\mathbb{Q}$, for example $e-1$ is irrational but $e-1 \in [1,2]$.

Comment: @SimonMueller Indeed. And… ? Isn't $\mathbb{R}^2$ the space that we're working with?

Comment: oh right........

Comment: But it cant be closed: look at the series with $e_n = (1+1/n)^n - 1$. All $(e_n,3) \in M$ but the limit $(e,3)$ is not in $M$ because $(e,3)\not\in\mathbb{Q}^2$. That means, that the set is open.

Comment: What do you say to this argument?

Comment: @SimonMueller When you assert that “it cant be closed”, what are you talking about? $M$ or its boundary?

Comment: I was talking about $M$

Comment: @SimonMueller **Of course** it is not closed! Didn't I write that $\overline M=[1,2]\times[3,4]$? Since $\overline M\neq M$, $M$ is not closed.

Comment: I thought "which is a closed set" was related to $M$. I apologize.

Comment: @SimonMueller No. It's the boundaty that it's a closed set (they always are).